# What is the best solution for communication between a collection of gRPC service written in GO and Javascript client?

Tags: reactjs, go, kubernetes, microservices, grpc

My plan is about making React application talk to set of gRPC micro-services deployed on Kubernetes (with Istio and Envoy). But after few implementation tries with different libraries such as grpc-gateway, grpc-web,... it seems like those libraries is not completely support gRPC. Each library lacks of some features which are "standards" in traditional XML/JSON over HTTP.

The points of my question are:

1. Is gRPC truly ready for production?
2. Do you have any recommendations for implementing micro-services in Go with gRPC to talk to web client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use grpc-web if you are using Istio, as Istio will automatically handle proxying your http/1 requests into the http/2 requests that your grpc service understands.

gRPC is ready for production and is used by many corporations.

My recommendation is to keep your code in a monorepo, use Bazel as your build system, and Istio as your service mesh.

The monorepo approach allows you to avoid one of the most painful aspects of dealing with gRPC / protobufs - the sharing of the proto files across language / client / service boundaries. (There are Bazel rules which create libraries from your proto files in various languages). The JavaScript rules are Beta quality as of November 2019 but they are quickly maturing.

Since you are already using Istio as your gRPC proxy you can take advantage of its other features, allowing you to move tracing, authentication, service discovery and other concerns out of your application code, so you can focus on business logic.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have a question, but what if i want to upload large files, is that true i have to implement a separate handler?

Comment: Phurong: I have run into this issue with trying to mix an actual file api with gRPC myself.  Their own docs basically say to not do that.  HTTP is what it is, and browsers expect a lot of detailed behavior; particularly with things like video and audio files.  User-facing APIs should be designed to play well with Javascript and browser media players.  gRPC is more of a backend thing, and you want an API that can do some RPC-like calls plus multipart-mime upload and download.  All REST+Json is fine.

Comment: for example: if you serve large files, the browser will start performing range requests on the bytes.  If you just use a generic gRPC to http gateway, you are going to just be dealing with a bunch of translation goo rather than getting it over with using an io.Copy and being done with it.  If a user wants the API to behave in a specific way, you can change the API directly; rather than fiddling with protobuf definitions until you get what you want as a side-effect.

Comment: Bidirectional streaming is currently in the works as per this grpc-web issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/24 . In the future, you'll be able to stream your file directly to the grpc backend. Also see the ROADMAP.MD document in the grpc-web repo.